# Javascript Binary Search prototype Array

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

Firstly you are to create three functions, as prototypes to the Array class to return the following:

```
toTwenty()` returns `[1, 2, 3 . . . 20]
```

below is the test case

```
describe('Binary Search to traverse an ordered list, effectively', function() {
  describe('Populate the arrays with valid content', function() {

    it('should create an array from 1 to 20, with intervals of 1', function() {
      expect(oneToTwenty[0]).toBe(1);
      expect(oneToTwenty[19]).toBe(20);
      expect(oneToTwenty.length).toBe(20);
      for(var i = 0; i < oneToTwenty.length - 1;i++) {
        expect(oneToTwenty[i + 1] - oneToTwenty[i]).toBe(1);
     }
    });
```

this is code below is my code but i keep getting

```
var oneToTwenty = [].toTwenty();
"TypeError: Object  has no method 'toTwenty'"
```

This is my code

```
function oneToTwenty(){

}

oneToTwenty.prototype.toTwenty = function(){
    var start = 1;
    var end = 20;
    var oneToTwenty = [];

for(var i = start; i <= end; i += 1){
    oneToTwenty.push(i);
}
   return oneToTwenty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `var oneToTwenty = [].toTwenty();` makes me think you're trying to change the Array prototype, not create a new type. You can't overwrite what array literals mean but you an add methods to native types:

```js
Array.prototype.toTwenty = function(){
    var start = 1;
    var end = 20;

    for(var i = start; i <= end; i += 1){
        this.push(i);
    }
   return this;
}

var oneToTwenty = [].toTwenty();

console.log(oneToTwenty); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

I don't think this is a good idea however. Changing native JavaScript types can interfere with how other libraries expect JavaScript to behave and if this were a popular thing to do libraries and code would be overwriting themselves constantly. Just build your own list type that makes use of arrays and leave the array itself. Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should.